# Determining big O running time for a program: if a separate function is called, do I include the operations in that too?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I've been given a simple pseudocode and told to determine the big O running time of the method myMethod() by counting the approximate number of operations it performs. However if within the function another function is called, do I include the operations from there as part of the running time of myMethod()?

I've been looking around the internet for answers but no luck so far, so I hope someone will be able to help me out here. Thank you

```
static int doIt(int n)
{
  count = 0
  j=1
  while j < n 
  {
   count = count +1
   j=j+2
  }
   return count
}


static int myMethod (int n)
{
  i = 1 
  while(i<n) 
 {
   dolt(i) 
   i = ix2 
 }
  return 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your runtime depends on everything that is called with it, *unless* the instructions say otherwise. The cost that you have from those functions is also scaled by the cost of evaluating the function as many times as it does.

For example, your bottom function has a while loop that runs around `lg n` times. You then also have to evaluate how the runtime is going to change based on the inputs, because the function calls you make also will vary due to your input. Since it's big-oh, you could set an upper bound and assume it for all invocations, however your bound may not be tight. Though from a theoretical point of view this is okay because big-oh is an upper bound.

If this is for say some school assignment, you will probably not get marks if your bounds aren't tight.